# Decoding json in array , editing array and encoding in json - PHP

Tags: php, json

I am newbee in php and trying to get json in array and wanna change key in that json below is my code :

```
   $json = json_decode(file_get_contents('all_json_files/jobs.json'), true); 
    foreach ($json as $key=>$row){
      foreach ( $row as $key=>$row){
         foreach ( $row as $key=>$row){
            foreach ($row as $key=>$row){
               if(strcmp($key,"security_block")==0)
                {
                       foreach ($row as $k=>$r){
                       if(strcmp($k,"job_payload_hash")==0)
                       {
                         $row[$k]['job_payload_hash']=$base64String;
                         print_r($row);
                       }
                }
              }
            }
         }
       }
    }
    print_r($json);
```

Issue is print_r($row); is updating properly but  print_r($json); does not print the updated string .

Comment: You know you can use json_decode() right?

Comment: `json_encode` and `json_decode` are your friends, those loops are crazy.

Comment: yes i know that things is i just want to chnage value of 'job_payload_hash' in my json @Varedis i-CONICA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the key could appear anywhere, the answer is pretty simple:

```
function update_hash(&$item, $key, $base64String)
{
    if ($key == "job_payload_hash") {
        $item = $base64String;
    }
}

array_walk_recursive($json, 'update_hash', 'something');
```

#### Update

The structure is something different that previously assumed; while the above will work, probably the below is a more direct approach:

```
foreach (array_keys($json['jobs']) as $jobId) {
    $json['jobs'][$jobId]['job']['security_block']['job_payload_hash'] = 'something';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `$key` & `$row`  variable in multiple time. for this reason, value of `$key`   is changed each time, so parent loop does not work..

You can use recursive function  lik answer of @Ja͢ck .

Answer (score -1):

Decode the JSON string using [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), edit your resulting array, then use [json_encode();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to return the array to a JSON encoded string.

Also, use [array_key_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) rather than comparing array key strings.

```php
$array = json_decode($json);

if(array_key_exists("job_payload_hash", $array){
  $array["job_payload_hash"] = base64encode($var);
}

$json = json_encode($array);
```

Comment: This only observes a single dimension; the data that needs to be changed seems to be five levels deep.

Comment: You're right, array_walk_recursive is better for this.

Answer (score -1):

this is because you have to save not in variables you defined after => in a foreach.
You have to store this in format:

```
$json[0][0] ... = $base64String;
```

OR

You have to add a new array like $result = array() before you write the foreach and then store it in $result.

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted, it's an answer in the right direction.

Comment: Because it tries to fix awful code. The OP is clearly going in the wrong direction. So a good answer would suggest a better way of coding the above, not help fix someone's crap code.